# Unexpected result in regex - what am I missing?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract immunization records of this form:

```
Immunization: Tetanus
Other: Booster 
Method: Injection
Date Received: 07 Jan 2013
```

and also of this form:

```
Immunization:   TETANUS DIPTHERIA (TD-ADULT)
Date Received:  07 Dec 2012 @ 1155
Location:       PORTLAND (OR) VAMC
Reaction:*      None Reported
Comments:       1234567
```

Here is my pattern string:

```
"Immunization:(.*?)\n[.\n*?]*?Date Received:(.*?)\n"
```

This is identifying the second pattern and extracting vaccination name and date but not the first pattern. I thought that `[.\n*?]*?` would take care of the two possibilities (that there are other fields between vaccination name and vaccination date...or not...but this doesn't seem to be doing the trick. What is wrong with my regex and how cna I fix it?

Comment: What flags are you using? Multiline?

Comment: How about you split the lines at `:` and strip spaces and `*`. You could easily generate a dictionary from the data.

Comment: Try `Immunization:\s+(.+?)\n.*?Date Received:\s+(.+?)\n` with the dotall flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r"Immunization:\s+(.*?)\s+.*?Date Received:\s+(.*?)$", subject, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OVNpVS/1) | [Python Demo](https://eval.in/803862)

---

Regex Explanation:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you explain why this works? In particular, what's up with not including anything as to the newline?

Comment: You're very welcome @RandoDoe. I've updated the answer with a regex explanation, in this case, you should have used the `re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE` flags.  GL!

Answer (score 0):

Tested this on pythex with MULTILINE and DOTALL:

Input

```
Immunization: Tetanus
Other: Booster 
Method: Injection
Date Received: 07 Jan 2013

Immunization:   TETANUS DIPTHERIA (TD-ADULT)
Date Received:  07 Dec 2012 @ 1155
Location:       PORTLAND (OR) VAMC
Reaction:*      None Reported
Comments:       1234567
```

Pattern: `Immunization:\s+(\w+).*?Date Received:\s+([^\n]+)`

#### Match 1

1. Tetanus
2. 07 Jan 2013

#### Match 2

1. TETANUS
2. 07 Dec 2012 @ 1155

[Pythex](http://pythex.org/?regex=Immunization%3A%5Cs%2B(%5Cw%2B).*%3FDate%20Received%3A%5Cs%2B(%5B%5E%5Cn%5D%2B)&test_string=Immunization%3A%20Tetanus%0AOther%3A%20Booster%20%0AMethod%3A%20Injection%0ADate%20Received%3A%2007%20Jan%202013%0A%0AImmunization%3A%20%20%20TETANUS%20DIPTHERIA%20(TD-ADULT)%0ADate%20Received%3A%20%2007%20Dec%202012%20%40%201155%0ALocation%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PORTLAND%20(OR)%20VAMC%0AReaction%3A*%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20Reported%0AComments%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%201234567%20&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=1&verbose=0)

[Pythex with different grouping](http://pythex.org/?regex=(Immunization%3A%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B).*%3F(Date%20Received%3A%5Cs%2B%5B%5E%5Cn%5D%2B)&test_string=Immunization%3A%20Tetanus%0AOther%3A%20Booster%20%0AMethod%3A%20Injection%0ADate%20Received%3A%2007%20Jan%202013%0A%0AImmunization%3A%20%20%20TETANUS%20DIPTHERIA%20(TD-ADULT)%0ADate%20Received%3A%20%2007%20Dec%202012%20%40%201155%0ALocation%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PORTLAND%20(OR)%20VAMC%0AReaction%3A*%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20Reported%0AComments%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%201234567%20&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=1&verbose=0)

Answer (score 0):

The . in [.\n] is taken as a literal '.', not as a symbol for any-character. This is why the date line immediately following the immunisation is accepted but you fail to jump across a character that is not a newline or a dot.

`(.*\n)*` comes to mind to help you out in the closest way to what you already have. However, it is a bit unfortunate to have so many nested * since this means a long breath for parsing the record and as a human I also find it more difficult to understand. It may be preferable to start every loop with a literal to help the decision making if a loop shall be entered/continued at all.

If I did not mess it up then

```
Immunization:(.*?)(\n.*)*\nDate Received:(.*)\n
```

would do without left recursion and "Date Received" would only be detected at the beginning of the line.